# How can I read all the bytes in a text file including new lines?

Tags: java, file, scala, newline, eol

I'm trying to write a simple class to detect the line terminator of a text file.
The idea is quite simple: count the occurrences of these three patterns
      ~  \n  ~  \r  ~  \r\n 
 
in the beginning of the file and return the pattern associated to the higher counter.

What I haven't got in two days is how to read the LF character (\n) in a variable (I'm on OS X). Everything I've tried so far seems to avoid LF from  being read. I know that's a typical behavior of Reader classes, but I also got the same problem using DataInputStream

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import scala.io.Codec

object EolDetection {

  def detect(file: File)(implicit codec: Codec): String = {
    detect(new FileInputStream(file))
  }
  def detect(is: InputStream)(implicit codec: Codec): String = {
    detect( new BufferedInputStream(is))
  }  
  def detect(bs: BufferedInputStream): String = {
    var LFcnt = 0 ; var CRLFcnt = 0 ; var CRcnt = 0 ; var wasCR = false
    try {
      var ascii = bs.read()
      while ( ascii > -1 && (LFcnt + CRLFcnt + CRcnt) < 11 ) {
        ascii match {
          case 13 => wasCR = true ; debug("A") 
          case 10 => if (wasCR) CRLFcnt += 1 else LFcnt += 1 ; wasCR = false ; debug("B")
          case  _ => if (wasCR) CRcnt += 1 ; wasCR = false; debug("C")
        }
        ascii = bs.read()
      }
      debug(s"\nLF=$LFcnt CRLF=$CRLFcnt CR=$CRcnt\n")
      var sep = "\n"
      if (LFcnt > CRLFcnt && LFcnt > CRcnt) sep = "\n"
      if (CRLFcnt > LFcnt && CRLFcnt > CRcnt) sep = "\r\n"
      if (CRcnt > CRLFcnt && CRcnt > LFcnt) sep = "\r"
      sep
    } finally {
      bs.close()
    }
  }

  def debug(msg: String) = printf(msg)
}
```

Any suggestion? If you know a project with such feature to add as a dependency, please let me know.

Comment: Use a Scanner? You can count how many times Scanner `.nextLine()` function runs.

Comment: Do you need to count each line-feed type separately, or just a total count for all line-feeds?

Comment: I need to count each type on possible EOL ( see the three patterns above). I assume the input may not be omogeneous, so the most frequent pattern will be elected the official EOL

Comment: Aify: I don't get what to do with .nextLine() count. Have you got what is my goal?

Comment: `Source.fromFile("foo.txt").mkString.linesWithSeparators.toList`. That method takes 0xa but preserves EOL for you. Or write your own, of course.